# grep foldername and sub file content

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, grep

i have a folder structure like:

`debug/$domain/info.txt`

in debug are like 200 domains

and i want to grep a specific content of the `info.txt` file for each domain
so i want to log down the domain + a content part of the `info.txt` which i need to grep.

i tried much stuff but i failed.

```
for D in $(find . -type d); do
  grep xxx D/info.txt 
done
```

if you got any idea how to be done, please let me know.

thanks :)

Comment: part of info.txt with the content is needed to build up a regex...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Comment: the regex for the content is done. simply pseudo stuff.

Comment: for D in `find . -type d`
do
    grep xxx D/info.txt 
done

Comment: @user5293028 What's the structure of `info.txt` and what do you want to match?

Comment: i dont need help for the regex, read first post pls

Comment: `a content part of the info.txt` Please post a sample input and the expected format of the log-file to make the question complete.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the regex part (finding content) already done, try something like this:

```
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    domain="${$REPLY##*/}"
    content="$(grep -o xxx $REPLY/info.txt)"
    echo "$domain: $content" >> log.txt
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

Or using your for loop attempt:

```
for D in $(find . -type d); do
  content="$(grep -o xxx D/info.txt)"
  domain="$D##*/"
  echo "$domain: $content" >>log.txt
done
```

Though remember that this for loop is **not** white space safe, though it doesn't matter for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Below script is another way of doing it:

```
find /path/to/search/for -type f -name "*info.txt" -print0 | while read -r -d '' line
do
domain=$(sed 's/^.*debug\/\(.*\)\/info.txt/\1/' <<<"$line")
content=$(grep "text_to_grab" "$line")
printf "%s : %s\n" "$domain" "$content" >>logfile
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the tag perl to your question, I provide a solution using Perl.

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;

my $search_for = qr{abc}; #string to search for

print search_info_files($search_for);

sub search_info_files {
    my $rex       = shift;
    my $file_name = 'info.txt';

    chdir 'debug' or die "Unable to chdir to debug: $!\n";

    my @domains = glob("*");

    foreach my $domain (@domains) {
        next unless -d $domain;
        next unless -f $domain . '/' . $file_name;

        open my $fh, '<', $domain . '/' . $file_name
          or die "Unable to open $domain/$file_name: $!\n";

        while (<$fh>) {
        chomp(my $line = $_);
            next unless $line =~ $rex;
            print "'$domain' matches (line#: $.): $line.\n";
        }

        close $fh;

    }
}
__END__
Sample output:
'a' matches (line#: 1): As easy as abc.
'b' matches (line#: 2): abcde.
'c' matches (line#: 1): abcde.
'c' matches (line#: 3): abcde.
'c' matches (line#: 5): Sometimes more than one line contains abc.
'd' matches (line#: 1): abcde.
'd' matches (line#: 3): abcde.
'e' matches (line#: 1): abcde.
```

For example debug/c/info.txt contains:

> ```
> abcde
> fghij
> abcde
> fffff
> Sometimes more than one line contains abc
> ```